# Fetch first character of each word in sqlite3 string

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite3 table we have names like as below.

```
Monty Python
Luther Blissett
Rey maR EsteBaN
Monty Cantsin
Geoffrey Cohen
Karen Eliot
Poor Konrad
```

I need a query to fetch the character from the database.

1. Initially I need a query that should fetch first letter of every word in a string. In above example it should display M, P, L, B, R, E, C, G, K
2. Suppose if a user selects C after the above query, then it should fetch next possible characters of  C**a**ntsin and C**o**hen i.e  A and O.

Please provide any inputs on how the solution can be arrived?

Comment: It is fine if it different queries to the database. Any solutions?

Comment: Are you sure, that your problem is best solved using multiple database queries? As an alternative consider querying the database once and write code that extracts the information.

Comment: Use [substr()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and [LIKE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like).

Comment: Could you please sql query for the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution below would work if only first name is taken to count.

Consider data:

```
    sqlite> SELECT name  FROM COMPANY;
    Paul Allen
    Mark
    Monty Python
    Luther Blissett
    Monty Cantsin
```

For 1st query:

```
    sqlite> SELECT distinct  substr(name,1,1)  FROM COMPANY;
    P
    M
    L
```

And later for 2nd output try below algorithm:

> - if you have 1 character input then use substr (name, 2,1)
> - if you have 2 characters input then use substr (name, 3,1)
> - .. generally : if x is number of characters input and y is number of character output expected, try **substr (name, x+1, y)**

```
    sqlite> SELECT distinct  substr(name,2,1)  FROM COMPANY where name like 'M%';
     a
     o


    sqlite> SELECT distinct  substr(name,3,1)  FROM COMPANY where name like 'Ma%';
    r
```

If others words also need to be considered for search, replace table name with sub queries as below.

```
SELECT distinct  substr(name,2,1)  FROM 
(
    select name from company where name like 'A%'  -- counts for first word
    UNION
    select name from company where name like '% A%' -- counts for words that start with space
);
```

Please note that above queries will only return the characters of first word, though the match is for all words it would consider first name as source to fetch characters.

Comment: This query gives only partial result. I need first character of every work in a string. That means for

Comment: Above query gives only partial result. I need fetch first character of every word in a string. That means for    
    Paul Allen         -     (First alphabets are P, A)
    Mark                 -     (First alphabets are M)
    Monty Python   -     (First alphabets are M, P)
    Luther Blissett  -     (First alphabets are L, B)
    Monty Cantsin  -     (First alphabets are M, C)

    it should print alphabets P, A, M, L, B, C. Any pointers?